# Discord.Py Discord Bot Failing to respond

Tags: python, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import discord
import datetime
NoKickedMember = discord.Embed(title="No un-verified members found", description="No members were found unverified or denied to the server so i have not kicked anyone.", color=0x10BDF6)
KickedMember = discord.Embed(title="Succesfully kicked unverified members", description="I have kicked everyone who failed to verify, or was denied", color=0x10BDF6)
NoPermissions= discord.Embed(title="You do not have the correct permissions to run this command", description="You need admin permissions to run this command as it can kick mass amount of members", color=0x10BDF6)

class KickAll(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.kickall_task.start() 
   

# Checks if they do not have perm to run command
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send(embed=NoPermissions)
  # Task that isnt updated yet, but does work.
    @tasks.loop(hours=168)  
    async def kickall_task(self):
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(1053331335005098044) 
        members = guild.members
        channel = guild.get_channel(1053331335005098047)
        KickedMembers = []
        for member in members:
            if not member.bot and member != guild.owner:  
                try:
                    if len(member.roles) == 1:
                        await member.send("")
                        await member.kick(reason="Did not verify in 3 day duration, or was denied.")
                        KickedMembers.append(member.name)
                except discord.Forbidden:
                    pass
        if KickedMembers:
            await channel.send(embed=KickedMember)
        else:
            await channel.send(embed=NoKickedMember)
# Command that is not working, currently updating
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def kickall(self,ctx):
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(1053331335005098044) 
        members = guild.members
        channel = guild.get_channel(1053331335005098047)
        KickedMembers = []
        for member in members:
            if not member.bot and member != guild.owner:  
                try:
                    CurrentTime = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - member.joined_at
                    if len(member.roles) == 1 and CurrentTime.days > 1:
                        await member.send("")
                        await member.kick(reason="Did not verify in 3 day duration, or was denied.")
                        KickedMembers.append(member.name)
                except discord.Forbidden:
                    pass
            if KickedMembers:
                await channel.send(embed=KickedMember)
            else:
                await channel.send(embed=NoKickedMember)
        
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(KickAll(bot))
```

My code is supposed to have a task that checks if a user has no roles or not, then kick & DM them if they meet the critieria. The bot should also send a message embed called NoKickedMember if the criteria is not met. The task is currently outdated so can be ignored although the command does not send NoKickedMember when the criteria is not met. Please also know the quotations that are empty is okay, i did this for posting.

Comment: Could be related to `color=0x10BDF6`. Try to use an actual color from d.py or use `from_rgb` to convert your color